# Error para saber quien esta conectado como FaceBook

Tags: php, mysql

Hola amigos tengo un error muy raro con mi code para ver quien esta conectado pero esto funciona cuando quiere hay uno's que salen online y hay otros offline y lo raro es que hay otros que ni sale nada porque pasa eso una ayuda para poder ver quien esta conectado y quien no igual que facebook en el menú de amigos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
session_start();
$userID = '9'; //user
$online = 'yes';
$time_check = $online-10; //We Have Set Time 1 Minutes


$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE userID='$userID'"; $result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result); 

//If count is 0 , then enter the values
if($count=="no"){ 
    $sql="INSERT INTO user(userID, online)VALUES('$userID', '$online')"; 
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
}

// else update the values 
else {
    $sql="UPDATE user SET online='$online' WHERE userID = '$userID'"; 
    $result=mysql_query($sql); 
}
```

Comment: Disculpa Shareiv, pero no logro entender tu pregunta. Por si acaso, te sugiero de volver a leer la pregunta poniéndote en nuestro lugar, o sea sin tener ningún contexto, y verifica si es que no faltan detalles importantes a la pregunta para que sea más entendible.

Comment: Tengo un par de dudas con el código, `$time_check = $online-10;` porqué haces una resta utilizando $online si este tiene el valor `'yes'`?, Luego en `if($count=="no"){ ` esta parte se supones que compruebas la cantidad de registros devuelta, pero lo comparas con `"no"`.

Answer (score 1):

Tu forma de declarar conección de PHP con MySQL ya no se aceptada por muchos de los servidores. Mira la versión de PHP que estás utilizando en tu servidor local (wamp/xamp..). Yo utilizo PHP 5.6 o PHP 7 y si yo escribiera conecciones como las haces tú: `mysql_query`, `mysql_num_rows` me daría error y si lo ignorara no me funcionaría la aplicación.

Si vas a publicar tú página en internet, fuertemente te sugiero cambiar tú código utilizando Mysqli ó PDO. Te lo he cambiado a PDO. No lo he testado, así que puede dar algun error:

```
session_start();
$userID = '9'; //user
$online = 'yes';
$time_check = $online-10; //We Have Set Time 1 Minutes

$sql=""; $result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result); 

$count = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE userID = $userID")->fetchColumn();

//If count is 0 , then enter the values
// !!!!! MIRA A VER SI EL COUNT TIENE QUE DECIR NO O TIENE QUE DECIR 0 PORQUE TU COMENTARIO DICE UNA COSA Y PONES OTRA
if($count=="no") { 
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO user(userID, online) VALUES ($userID, $online)");
    $stmt->execute();
}

// else update the values 
else {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE user SET online = $online WHERE userID = $userID");
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

PERO PRIMERO haz una conección con PDO:

```
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'test';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
```

Comment: estoy usando php 5.5 con mysql una pregunta que diferencia hay com mysqli? y cambiar todo mi codigo a PHP 7 PDO QUIERO PERO SON 37 FILES

Comment: Te entiendo perfectamente @Shareiv pero para estar al día en este sector hay que dedicar tiempo e intentar cosas nuevas. Con PDO te vas a volver más productivo, tú sistema estará asegurado.. No sé qué hosting utilizas, pero el mío me cobraría por php 5.5 porqué ya no hay soporte general para ello ... Php 7.0 tiene soporte general gratis por lo menos hasta 2019... ¿Porqué no utilizar `mysql_query` ? En inglés: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12860046/4539498